# How to prepare my data fo a factorial repeated measures analysis?

Tags: r, reshape, glm, reshape2

Currently, my dataframe is in wide-format and I want to do a factorial repeated measures analysis with two between subject factors (sex & org) and a within subject factor (tasktype). Below I've illustrated how my data looks with a sample (the actual dataset has a lot more variables). The variable starting with '1_' and '2_' belong to measurements during task 1 and task 2 respectively. this means that **1_FD_H_org** and **2_FD_H_org** are the same measurements but for tasks 1 and 2 respectively.

```
id  sex  org  task1     task2  1_FD_H_org  1_FD_H_text  2_FD_H_org  2_FD_H_text  1_apv  2_apv
2   F    T    Correct   2      69.97       68.9         116.12      296.02       10     27
6   M    T    Correct   2      53.08       107.91       73.73       333.15       16     21
7   M    T    Correct   2      13.82       30.9         31.8        78.07        4      9
8   M    T    Correct   2      42.96       50.01        88.81       302.07       4      24
9   F    H    Correct   3      60.35       102.9        39.81       96.6         15     10
10  F    T    Incorrect 3      78.61       80.42        55.16       117.57       20     17
```

I want to analyze whether there is a difference between the two tasks on e.g. FD_H_org for the different groups/conditions (sex & org).

How do I reshape my data so I can analyze it with a model like this?
`ezANOVA(data=df, dv=.(FD_H_org), wid=.(id), between=.(sex, org), within=.(task))`

I think that the correct format of my data should like this:

```
id  sex  org  task  outcome   FD_H_org   FD_H_text  apv
2   F    T    1     Correct   69.97      68.9       10
2   F    T    2     2         116.12     296.02     27
6   M    T    1     Correct   53.08      107.91     16
6   M    T    2     2         73.73      333.15     21
```

But I'm not sure. I tryed to achieve this wih the `reshape2` package but couldn't figure out how to do it. Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think probably you need to rebuild it by binding the 2 subsets of columns together with rbind(). The only issue here was that your outcomes implied difference data types, so forced them both to text:

```
require(plyr)
dt<-read.table(file="dt.txt",header=TRUE,sep=" ") # this was to bring in your data

newtab=rbind(
  ddply(dt,.(id,sex,org),summarize, task=1, outcome=as.character(task1), FD_H_org=X1_FD_H_org, FD_H_text=X1_FD_H_text, apv=X1_apv),
  ddply(dt,.(id,sex,org),summarize, task=2, outcome=as.character(task2), FD_H_org=X2_FD_H_org, FD_H_text=X2_FD_H_text, apv=X2_apv)
)

newtab[order(newtab$id),]

     id sex org task   outcome FD_H_org FD_H_text apv
  1   2   F   T    1   Correct    69.97     68.90  10
  7   2   F   T    2         2   116.12    296.02  27
  2   6   M   T    1   Correct    53.08    107.91  16
  8   6   M   T    2         2    73.73    333.15  21
  3   7   M   T    1   Correct    13.82     30.90   4
  9   7   M   T    2         2    31.80     78.07   9
  4   8   M   T    1   Correct    42.96     50.01   4
  10  8   M   T    2         2    88.81    302.07  24
  5   9   F   H    1   Correct    60.35    102.90  15
  11  9   F   H    2         3    39.81     96.60  10
  6  10   F   T    1 Incorrect    78.61     80.42  20
  12 10   F   T    2         3    55.16    117.57  17
```

EDIT - obviously you don't need plyr for this (and it may slow it down) unless you're doing further transformations. This is the code with no non-standard dependencies:

```
  newcolnames<-c("id","sex","org","task","outcome","FD_H_org","FD_H_text","apv")
  t1<-dt[,c(1,2,3,3,4,6,8,10)]
  t1$org.1<-1
  colnames(t1)<-newcolnames
  t2<-dt[,c(1,2,3,3,5,7,9,11)]
  t2$org.1<-2
  t2$task2<-as.character(t2$task2)
  colnames(t2)<-newcolnames
  newt<-rbind(t1,t2)
  newt[order(newt$id),]
```